# Simultaneous building and creating installation package for crossplatform application on different OS when source code changed

Tags: installation, continuous-integration

For example, I have several Operation Systems in my virtual network, such as:

- Windows 7
- Fedora 17
- Ubuntu 12.10
- Mac OS X

and possibly others (in the future).

All Operating Systems have access to mercurial repository of my crossplatform application (for example written in Qt).

When I edit my source code anywhere and push it to mercurial I want it to start building and creating install package for all the above Operating Systems.

In the output, I want to have install packeges for each of the Operating Systems on my virtual network.

What solutions already exist to solve my problem?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: If I read you correctly, it seems like you want something that automatically does all this for you after pushing. I for one have never heard of such an automatic system.

Comment: System, that do something after pushing exist. For example - TeamCity. But, i dont know is this program suitable for my problem.

Comment: Wow, I've learned about something I didn't even imagine existed. I'm kind of new getting back into programming again, and am trying to do crossplatform stuff. As for whether this works for you, I'm not quite sure, it's pretty big stuff, and looks quite capable, but I've never used it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about sounds very much like [build automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) or possibly [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Numerous products exist which basically sit on a server and monitor your source control repository, waiting for changes. When they find them, they can perform pretty much any action that can be automated. Most are designed to make tasks such as building a project, performing unit tests, pushing artifacts to FTP and so on straightforward.

In your case, you'd probably want to add an automation step to invoke an installation package compiler such as MSI or InnoSetup each time a successful build completes.

I have used [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) in the past, but numerous others exist. Googling 'build automation' is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you very much! But i thought that exist more easy way for perform my task.

Comment: @Milovidov - Jenkins is pretty easy to set up. Download the .jar and run it, basically. Of course it doesn't do anything unless you add projects, but there are few barriers to entry. You *could* set up the various automation actions up as post-build steps in your IDE instead, but that's a less-nice solution.